# Nginx won't start

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I recently installed Nginx on ubuntu, and I want to run it, so i use the nginx command, but I got this error.

```
root@kevin-virtual-machine:/etc/nginx# nginx
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to [::]:80 failed (98: Unknown error)
nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
root@kevin-virtual-machine:/etc/nginx#
```

Ii haven't done anything, I just installed it and it doesn't work.

I tried searching for the solution, but I haven't found one yet.

Comment: check logs at /var/log/nginx/error.log , tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: @niko the error log just said unknown error

Comment: Check logs, and try restart nginx service and u may write command sudo nginx -t (check syntax)
if u receive a message "nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok" - try going to localhost:80, else fix syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Try these commands

```bash
sudo netstat -tuln | grep :80 # This is for finding confilicts in the same port
```

Restart nginx

```bash
sudo systemctl stop nginx
```

Find errors in the script :

```bash
sudo nginx -t
```

If none of them worked, try using port 8080 instead of port 80.

Comment: i tried using port 8080 and it didn't resolve the error, i think it is important to share that i ran apache in the same VM, i already ran "systemctl stop apache2" but it still didn't work

Comment: That's what I did.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by killing the Nginx processes. Here is what I did:

1. I get the process ID's of every Nginx process.

```
     pgrep nginx
```

2. Then I kill every process, given the process ID

```
     kill [process id]
```

3. Then I restarted nginx

```
    sudo service nginx restart
```

Comment: That's what I did, But in another way.